# Prove inequality using Chebyshev’s Inequality

Tags: probability

Using Chebyshev’s Inequality prove that

$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\leq\dfrac{\mathbb{E}\left|X\right|^{n}}{\epsilon^{n}}$ for $\epsilon >0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2):

Chebyshev’s Inequality gives you $\mathbb{P}(X\geq\delta)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}X}{\delta}$. Then you know $\mathbb{P}(|X|\geq\epsilon)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}|X|}{\epsilon}$ and $\mathbb{P}(|X|^n\geq\epsilon^n)\leq\frac{\mathbb{E}|X|^n}{\epsilon^n}$. So it would be enough to show $\mathbb{P}(|X|^n\geq\epsilon^n)=\mathbb{P}(|X|\geq\epsilon)$ but $\phi(x)=x^n$ is a strictly increasing function on $[0,\infty)$ thus $|x|\geq\epsilon\iff|x|^n\geq\epsilon^n$. This gives us $\{|X|\geq\epsilon\}=\{|X|^n\geq\epsilon^n\}$ as sets which implies they have the same probability.